# Current Capacity of Rectangular hollow copper bar

Tags: current-measurement, high-current

I have visited various site which include the table for current capacity of insulated wire and the busbar but no a single website gave the any particular equation or any calculation to measure current capacity of rectangular hollow copper bar with any thickness

[image: Text]

It would be grateful if you guys would do any help.

If anyone can make me formula as it is there in busbar which is 1.2 time the area of conductor for copper.

Current Capacity (in amps) = 1.2 * (area of conductor)

And Also how long our conductor is does it depends or not as a factor of current capacity?

And the ambient temperature would be 40 °C and we would cool the pipe by flowing water from hollow space in pipe.

[image: Text]

I want to run almost 3000 DC amps in the hollow copper pipe with measurement of 18x23mm and 4 mm thickness inside. So it would be possible to run that much amount of dc amps through the 22 sets of coil each coil consist of 20 meter long copper pipe.

So I will be able to run it or not. or something disaster happens

Comment: Start by working out the cross-sectional area of the conductor. Then find the equivalent solid. The hollow section should run a lot cooler due to increased surface area so you may find that voltage drop is a more significant parameter to work on.

Comment: No simple, single equation because ampacity is defined by maximum tolerable temperature and the environment determines what temperature the conductor reaches. In theory, you can run current until the copper itself melts if nothing around it (like insulation or mounting points) melts or burns first. Best just to look at a table for a similar cross section of wire with no insulation (or very high temperature insulation) and go with that, knowing that the limiting temperature in those tables is the insulation (or some other maximum allowable temperature which should be stated).

Comment: AC or DC matters, too, because of skin effect.  I'd have to do a lot of wacky math that I haven't touched in over 30 years to even know if the square bar makes a difference from round for AC (I think it does, but -- wacky math).

Comment: And if you have large metal mounting points for your copper bar you can probably run *way* more current than any table will tell you so you probably have other considerations there beyond heat (such as voltage drop).

Comment: Busbars are typically solid, not hollow, which is where 1.2 A / 1 mm^2 for copper comes from.  What current will be flowing?

Comment: @TimWescott its DC

Comment: Continuously or for a short while? If you pass cold water on the inside I would expect it to be able to carry huge amount of current while cool to the touch. Have you tried a FEM analysis or just a simple 2D calculation of the temperature gradient?

Comment: You have to get current there and back?  Voltage?  How are you planning to protect conductor from a person touching it?  Application?  Don't get me wrong!  It is interesting!

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I would imagine so. A circuit is always a loop. If not, charge would build up (and at the rate of \$3000\:\text{A}\$ I'd say "very quickly") and lead to arcing, discharge, or moving the moon itself away from the Earth! Electric charge is a very, very, very powerful force. And pumping this back through an earth ground? Egads! Think of the ground-voltage difference!

Comment: @jonk I assume so also, but does the OP, since a lot of key points have been left out!

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Yeah. A LOT is missing. Most "in my face" is the voltage drop. At that current? I'm trying to imagine but I'm finding it difficult to come up with any sensible guess. This has to come from the OP. Second for me is that I see square copper pipe and then a coil of circular copper pipe. Why the second picture, I wonder?

Comment: @jonk Because OP wants to use 22 runs of 20m of that pipe!

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Hmm. This must be a giant inductor of some kind. What else would make sense? Then the return point is the same as the starting point. Magnetic field? I don't think I've ever computed values for an air inductor with 3.2 m radius, 3000 A, and 22 loops (length being a big question then, as fringing is an issue.)

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat If this is an air inductor, I'm working out something on the order of \$20\:\mu\text{T}\$ as the field intensity within the coil. Thereabouts, anyway. I wonder what the OP is up to here. Who'd want to expose a sailboat to that field? On the other hand, if this is some particle accelerator device it may be appropriate to have something this large as then the field near the center would be quite uniform and charged particles would helically rotate as they travel. They should disclose, I think.

Comment: You had better answer some of the comments cause @jonk is going all evil lair over this!

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Geez. I took a break from the garage, where I'm build a huge coil of copper right now, and see your comment. What "evil lair?" It's just a garage out here. I've got to work out a source of 3000 amps for the coils, though. Since I'm in the ballpark of having to jam about 30 Joules of energy into the darned thing I'm considering a small charge of mercury fulminate crystals, pulling out my copy of [this book](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/p611) in order to get the required pulsed current. I'll get out some mercury, 70% nitric acid and get back to work...

Comment: What fluid will be moving through the interior of the channel?  How fast? Is boiling permitted?